# htaccess condition specific pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am having a little issue with my htaccess, what my goal is and what is currently working on my WordPress site is:

```
/blog/title-of-blog-post/1923
```

is being redirected to

```
/title-of-blog-post/
```

That is done with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/.*/$ $1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

However, that means it is also redirecting

```
/blog/page/2/ to /page/
/blog/page/3/ to /page/
etc
```

Is there a condition to which I could stop the /blog/page/nr being redirected, but still keep those rules as they are?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) before your rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/page/[0-9]+/?$
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)/.*/?$ $1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

You could probably optimize it a bit if needed.

Hope it helps you forward.

Comment: Thanks for your time Qben, unfortunately the condition does not seem to work at all for me, even if I was extremely specific with it, would you be able to help further at all?

Comment: @Jamie000012 I found that I was missing `/?` in the start of the `RewriteRule` and this made it not match my input. Try it again. Also added an optional `/` in the end of the `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Thanks Qben, with a little adjusting it's all working. :-) Many thanks